# lower bound of $n(n-1)(n-2) \dots (n-k)$

Tags: inequality, permutations, combinations, upper-lower-bounds

Is there any tight lower bound on following expression for $n\geq k$

$$n(n-1)(n-2) \dots (n-k+1)$$

one lower bound I could think is $(n-k+1)^k$. But  I need to find $f$ s.t

$$f(k) n^{k} \leq n(n-1)(n-2) \dots (n-k+1)$$

my attempt using stirling's approximation

$$n(n-1)(n-2) \dots (n-k+1) = k! \binom{n}{k} \geq \sqrt{2\pi}k^{k} \sqrt{k} e^{-k} . (n/k)^{k} = \Big[\sqrt{2\pi k} e^{-k}\Big] n^k $$. I need to know if I can remove $e^{-k}$ in above and get something more like $k^{-c}$, atleast when $k$ is small.  Any pointers and suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What restrictions are there on your $f$, like what exactly do you mean by "tight", is there an error bound that you need to surpass?

Comment: @Mo145. edited now

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Shouldn't your $n-k-1$ be $n-k+1$? As it stands, your product has $k+2$ terms.

Comment: @TonyK. True and corrected.

Answer (score 1):

$$n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k)=\frac{n!}{(n-(k+1))!}=\binom{n}{k+1}(k+1)!$$

Now we know that $$\left(\frac{n}{k+1}\right)^{k+1} \leq {n \choose k+1} \leq \left( \frac{en}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}$$
Therefore we get that
$$\left(\frac{n}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}(k+1)!\leq n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k)\leq\left( \frac{en}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}(k+1)!$$
where $e=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}$